# How to split a string containing a hyphen in perl

Tags: regex, perl, split, substr

I have a string referred to as ($date) that I am trying to split into two parts using Perl.

```
$date= (June 25, 2018–July 1, 2018)
```

From what I have read it seems that the proper way to split this string into the two separate dates would be to create a new array, use the Perl split() function with the hyphen as a delimiter and then assign the array index values to my StartDate/EndDate variables like this...

```
@dates = split(/-/, $date);
  $StartDate = @dates[0];
  $EndDate = @dates[1];

print "Effective Date: ($date)\n";
print "($StartDate)";
print "\n";
print "($EndDate)";
```

However this does not work as I expected it to.

Please keep in mind that the code above is only a small section of the source code.

```
Current Output (Incorrect)

Effective Date: (June 25, 2018–July 1, 2018)
(June 25, 2018–July 1, 2018)
()
```

Expected Output (Correct)

```
Effective Date: (June 25, 2018–July 1, 2018)
(June 25, 2018)
(July 1, 2018)
```

Looking for any advice on how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: You are using the wrong character for the split. Your dates string literal uses a long dash (–), while your split function call is using a regular hyphen. I just tried copying the character from the string directly and pasting as separator in the split call and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. In my actual source code I am utilizing both of those options. This post only contains a small portion of the source code.

Comment: Try `@dates = split(/\p{Dash}/, $date);` Or `@dates = split(/[\x{2D}\x{58A}\x{5BE}\x{1400}\x{1806}\x{2010}-\x{2015}\x{2053}\x{207B}\x{208B}\x{2212}\x{2E17}\x{2E1A}\x{2E3A}-\x{2E3B}\x{2E40}\x{301C}\x{3030}\x{30A0}\x{FE31}-\x{FE32}\x{FE58}\x{FE63}\x{FF0D}]/, $date);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to split on `-` (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS) but your string contains `–` (U+2013 EN DASH).

There are a couple of ways you can specify this character in a regex:

```
use utf8;
...
my ($StartDate, $EndDate) = split /–/, $date;
```

`use utf8` tells perl that your source code is in UTF-8, so you can use Unicode characters literally.

```
my ($StartDate, $EndDate) = split /\x{2013}/, $date;
```

Or you can use a hex character code.

```
my ($StartDate, $EndDate) = split /\N{EN DASH}/, $date;
```

Or a named character reference.

If you don't necessarily want to split on EN DASH but any dash-like character, you can use a character class based on the "Dash" property:

```
my ($StartDate, $EndDate) = split /\p{Dash}/, $date;
```

---

Note that `@dates[0]` will trigger a warning (if `use warnings` is enabled, which it should be) because a single element of an array `@foo` is spelled `$foo[0]` in Perl. The syntax `@array[ LIST ]` is used for array slices, i.e. extracting multiple elements by their indices.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for and helped fix my problem! You're the best!